# A Linux tool to zero-fill free space *and* cluster tips on an NTFS volume

Tags: linux, wiping

I'm looking for a text-based Linux tool which I can use from a custom bootable CD to wipe the free space (`zerofree` or `dd if=/dev/zero of=/zerofile bs=1M || rm /zerofile` will do this) **and** the cluster tips.

An additional requirement is that the tool not tamper with the NTFS version of the mounted disk.